# How to convert from D3 svg to topojson/geojson?

Tags: svg, d3.js, geojson, topojson

D3 allows to convert geojson/topojson arrays of points'  coordinates

```
[ [x,y],[x,y],[x,y],...]    // aka, a geojson arc.
```

And, via a projection, into svg paths

```
<path d="M x,y x,y x,y ..."></path>  // aka, an svg-xml path
```

Note: the values actually change. Topojson points `[x,y]`, are transformed via `projection([x,y])` into new values for the svg's path.

So, if we store in the svg:

1. the projection name
2. the points absolute coordinates relative to the svg origine 0,0 (already stored in the path).
3. Use `projection.invert()`

We could convert from xml svg back into topojson/shp, including the hand added shapes and layers.

I am unaware so far of any open source tool doing so.

Question become: **What minimal requirements should i store in my svg so it keep the potential to be converted back into GIS formats ?** (i may have missed some points)

---

**Edit:** While aware about it, the complexity of handling `Point`, `LineString`, `Polygon`, `MultiPoints`, `MultiLineStrings`, `MultiPolygons` is not the issue right now. Just the minimal requirements so backward conversion stays possible.

**Edit2:** convert back to geojson would likely be easier, since the svg and geojson data structures are more similar.

Comment: @StephenThomas: I know, i just start the talk about "what would be need so such functions could work".